# switch solaris 9 sparc console to ttya from screen without a reboot

Tags: solaris, console

We have a Sun Netra that someone booted with a monitor connected to the VGA output and the
console went to screen.
I'd like to switch that to serial without a reboot,
I tried

```
eeprom output-device=ttya
eeprom input-device=ttya
```

which is accepted but not enough, I am afraid it's still on screen.
Is there any mean to switch it at runtime without rebooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't switch the console after boot.